# Get Windows Update notification level using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I am looking to get the notification level of Windows Server 2016/2012 using Powershell. My goal is to change all of my servers' default status '0 - Enable Automatic Updates' to '3 - Auto download and notify for install' using powershell if the current status is 0.

So far I managed to use this command successfully:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU -Name AUOptions -Value 3
```

I would like to know if there is another way of doing this and also I need a command which will help me retrieve the current windows updates status before changing it to 3.

Any suggestion will be great!!

Comment: `I would like to know if there is another way of doing this` - You can use Group Policy to configure Windows Update settings.

Comment: Thank you @joeqwerty, I am aware of the group policy option and looking for a pure Powershell way.

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty` will allow you to read the current value. If you want to make the change on multiple machines with Powershell, take a look at PowerShell remote, or PowerShell DSC. But unless you're working on machines not joined to a domain, things like this are really easier with GPO as @joeqwerty suggested.

Comment: Group Policy is fine for machines that are re-deployed infrequently and are not time sensitive for when the policy is applied. The policy is fine also for maintaining the setting for the future (see also: DSC).  If you are doing an initial deployment of the servers and/or update orchestration, consider either pre-baking the registry key into the image and/or directly setting the registry key.  Group policy adds a lot of moving pieces that can go wrong, particularly when trying to maintain a secure environment.